# How i can add function to already exist function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have function.php in plugin. (This plugin works with the theme).

In already exist **function.php** have

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_tmp_register', 'tmp_register' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_tmp_register', 'tmp_register' );

function tmp_register() {

...bla bla

}
```

How i can add some my_own function to this already exists function?

Im try already by

```
if( !function_exists('tmp_register') )

add_filter('tmp_register', 'my_register', 10, 1);

if( !function_exists('tmp_register') ) {
    function my_register(){

        $usermobile          = trim( sanitize_text_field( wp_kses( $_POST['usermobile'], $allowed_html ) ));

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_mobile_meta_value', $usermobile );

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the hook and then add with the function you want.
In your theme's functions.php

```
remove_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_tmp_register', 'tmp_register' );
remove_action( 'wp_ajax_tmp_register', 'tmp_register' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_tmp_register', 'your_own_tmp_register' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_tmp_register', 'your_own_tmp_register' );
function your_own_tmp_register(){
/*do what you need*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try. If i will do like that, all actions and functions in tmp_register will be overwritten?

Comment: To be sure you lose anything, copy the content of function tmp_register into your_own_tmp_register and made the changes you need.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you know ...maybe... how make like a add_filter maybe? I want this function work both